# Attempting to have cart update each value individually instead of updating all of them

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, e-commerce, session-variables

I am making an e-commerce website and I have run into an issue with updating item quantity. When I go back to the same page of an item already in my cart and put in a new quantity, I return to my cart page and all of the items now have the same quantity as the item last updated.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['shoppingcart'])) {
        $_SESSION['shoppingcart'] = array();
        $_SESSION['name'] = array();
        $_SESSION['quantity'] = array();
        $_SESSION['price'] = array();
    }

    if (in_array($_POST['id'], $_SESSION['shoppingcart'])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['quantity']); $i++) {

            $_SESSION['quantity'][$i] = $_POST['quantity']; /*<-- I am thinking it is this piece right here.*/

            removeItemsZero($i);
            $added = '<p class="addedupdatemsg">Updated cart! Click <a href="catalog.php">here</a> to continue shopping!</p>';
        }
    } else {
            $_SESSION['shoppingcart'][] = $_POST['id'];
            $_SESSION['quantity'][] = $_POST['quantity'];
            $_SESSION['name'][] = $name;
            $_SESSION['price'][] = $price;
            $added = '<p class="addedupdatemsg">Product added! Click <a href="catalog.php">here</a> to continue shopping!</p>';
        }
```

> I am assuming it has something to do with $_SESSION['quantity'][$i] = $_POST['quantity']; piece, but I am unsure of any other ways to update the quantity on the product description page.

EDIT

I changed some things around, but now regardless of whichever product from the product page I select, I can't seem to change the quantity of that item specifically, but that value I enter into the field gets applied to the first index of the quantity array.

```
if (in_array($_POST['id'], $_SESSION['shoppingcart'])) {
        $key = array_search($_POST['id'], $_SESSION['quantity']);
            $_SESSION['quantity'][$key] = $_POST['quantity'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['quantity']); $i++) {
            removeItemsZero($i);
            $added = '<p class="addedupdatemsg">Updated cart! Click <a href="catalog.php">here</a> to continue shopping!</p>';
        }
```

> EDIT2

This is the code for the cart page with checkout

```
$cartTable = '<table class="carttable">';
$tableHeader = '<tr><th>NAME</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>PRICE</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>';
$endTable = '</table>';
$total = 0;
$totalDiscounted = 0;
$emptyCart = '';
$msg = '';
if (!empty($_SESSION['shoppingcart'])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['quantity']); $i++) {
            $postID = 'qty' . $i;
            $_SESSION['quantity'][$i] = $_POST[$postID];
            removeItemsZero($i);
        }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['purchase'])) {
    $msg = '<p>Thanks for purchasing! This is what you ordered</p><br>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['shoppingcart']); $i++) {
        $list .= '<div class="orderwrapper"><p class="orderheadertxt">Order List</p><ul><li>' . $_SESSION['quantity'][$i] . ' ' . $_SESSION['name'][$i] . '</li></ul></div>';
    }
    unset($_SESSION['shoppingcart']);
}
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['shoppingcart']);
    $emptyCart = '<p>Your cart is empty!</p>';
} else if(isset($_POST['purchase'])){
    $emptyCart = '<p>Your cart is now empty!</p>';
}else
{
    $emptyCart = '<p>Your cart is empty!</p>';
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Acme Online Store - cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="navtitle"><h2>Acme Online Store</h2></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="catalog.php">Products</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="cart.php">Cart</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="containercart">
    <form method="post">
        <?php
        if (!empty($_SESSION['shoppingcart'])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['shoppingcart']); $i++) {
            $cart .= '<tr>';
            $cart .= '<td>' . $_SESSION['name'][$i] . '</td>';
            $cart .= '<td><input type="text" id="quantity"name="qty' . $i . '"value="' . $_SESSION['quantity'][$i] . '" onkeyup="checkInput()"></td>';
            $cart .= '<td>$' . $_SESSION['price'][$i] . '</td>';
            $cart .= '<td>$' . $_SESSION['quantity'][$i] * $_SESSION['price'][$i] . '</td>';
            $cart .= '</tr>';
            $total += ($_SESSION['quantity'][$i] * $_SESSION['price'][$i]);
            $totalDiscounted += ($_SESSION['quantity'][$i] * $_SESSION['price'][$i]) / 100 * 30;
        }
        echo $cartTable;
        echo $tableHeader;
        echo $cart;
        echo $endTable;
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<p>All orders are 30% off for the holidays!</p><br>';
        echo '<table class="totaltable">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Total</th><th>Total After Discount</th><th>Savings</th></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td> $' . $total . '</td>';
        echo '<td>$' . number_format((float)$total - $totalDiscounted, 2, '.', '') . '</td>';
        echo '<td>$' . number_format((float)$totalDiscounted, 2, '.', '') . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
        ?>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Your line `if (in_array(...)` makes it appear as though each purchase item has a separate ID (e.g., apples have an ID and quantity) but then in your first for loop, you don't differentiate between any IDs. when assigning back to the Session Quantity amount. As for data structure, your shopping cart should probably contain an array of items that have names, quantities, etc.

Comment: I am unsure of how I need to go about assigning the  id to the quantity? I have these arrays acting as separate arrays, then they link to the shopping cart and display each of the values in each array. I have just been trying random things to try and understand this, but I am seemingly failing to do so.

Comment: I changed some things around and now it only updates the first index of the quantity array no matter which product I change the quantity on. I really don't understand what I am supposed to do to get the matching product to update the quantity of that item specifically.

Comment: I think more information is still needed. I have no idea if the user is updating multiple items at once or if you are designing to only update item. Regardless, your edit is closer except you need to find which index corresponds with `id` and `shoppingcart`. Assuming it's only one item being updated, then you would update that index of your `quantity`.

Comment: So, I have it set up where there is a product page, you select the item and it takes you to a product details page, the user can then add a quantity of this product and if it doesn't exist yet in array, it creates a new product and adds to the cart. If they visit that page again, they can change the quantity, but instead of adding a whole new item, it is supposed to just update the cart quantity of that item instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to include a self-contained example, but here is one method. We are saving the ID as the key to an array. That is, `array(1 => array(quantity = 10));` would be the data structure of the items within our shopping cart. This approach means we are determining whether the key exists and then updating shopping cart array.

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['shoppingcart'])) {
    $_SESSION['shoppingcart'] = array();
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $postId = cleanInput($_POST["id"]);
    $postQuantity = cleanInput($_POST['quantity']);
    if (!empty($_SESSION['shoppingcart'][$postId])) {
        $_SESSION['shoppingcart'][$postId]['quantity'] = $postQuantity;
        // you can add code that you updated existing record
    } else {
        $_SESSION['shoppingcart'][$postId] = array("quantity" => $postQuantity);
        // you can add code that you added a new record
    }
}

function cleanInput(string $data) : string
{
    $data = trim($data); // removes whitespace
    $data = stripslashes($data); // strips slashes
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data); // replaces html chars
    return $data;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Shopping Cart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method = "post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <label for = "id" name = "id">Enter Id</input><br>
            <input type="number" for = "id" name = "id" required><br>
            <label for = "quantity" name = "quantity">Enter Quantity</input><br>
            <input type="number" for = "quantity" name = "quantity" required><br> 
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php 
            if (count($_SESSION['shoppingcart']) == 0) {
                echo "<h2>No orders entered!</h2>";
            } else {
                echo "<table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>quantity</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>";
                foreach($_SESSION['shoppingcart'] as $id =>$shoppingItem) {
                    $quantityRes = $shoppingItem['quantity'];
                    echo "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$quantityRes</td></tr>";
                }
                echo " </tbody></table>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: I see, but is there any way I can keep my original code and still edit the quantity amount? Because if I change it, it completely breaks my cart page. Will add edit for cart page.

Comment: I guess you can loop through the shopping cart and find the index which equals what's posted. However, that approach you will always be fighting the data structure. I would recommend refactoring your code - note I even included initial code to show how a table could be made using my data structure. I'd be happy to provide some consultation, but I am not making additional edits for this.